# how to convert java desktop application into web application

Tags: java, swing, jakarta-ee

I have made a Java desktop application which simply stores information about the customers.
Now I'm asked to make the necessary changes to make it a web application.
I'm completely new to Java web development.

What I understand is that I will be given a server and I have to keep the program in that and only the admin will be able to run the program.

Can I just link to the application by some script so that my main program remains unchanged?
My application is based on Swing and a simple file based database.

Comment: sorry i don't know about this terminology :(

Comment: Try [Webswing](https://www.webswing.org) it renders any Swing application GUI in the browser using HTML5 Canvas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must determine what type of web application you want: servlet or applet? Also you can switch to an application type JavaFX. For starters try reading something about the basic structure of cups types of applications. For using applet see [How to convert a Swing Application to an Applet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651470/how-to-convert-a-swing-application-to-an-applet)

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Java Web Start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/index.html) as a means of deploying your Swing application. You should be able to avoid a re-write of your application depending on the end-user requirements.

Answer (score 2):

> Can i just link to the application by some script so that my main program remains unchanged ?

The simple answer is No.

I recommend that you get some training on how to write web applications in Java.  After you've done that, you will have a better idea of what needs to be done.

---

Note that both Applets and JWS would involve the user installing Java on his PC in order to run your code.

- In the former case, the user must enable a Java plugin in his web browser, and that represents a significant security risk.
- In the latter case, you don't has a "web application" in the normal sense.  Rather you have a regular Java application that is *launched* from the web.  (Storing data on the server is a problem that you still have to solve ...)